# Android communication with server via JSON

Tags: android, json

I just got placed in an IT company. They gave me android to work on. I am having trouble deciding what to learn on the topic. The server side is using JSON objects. Can someone tell me what topics i should learn to communicate with it.

Should i learn volley or something else?

Comment: If you were placed on that team, they probably should already have an HTTP library in place in the app. If it **is** Volley, then go ahead and learn it, but there are at least 5 other HTTP libraries for Android

Comment: Go for retrofit.

Answer (score 0):

first learn about AsyncTask. (it will teach you how to get data from server) a
2) learn about JSON notation, you will come to know how to parse json

Comment: I am familiar with those.I created apps which downloads json,parse it and then display it .What i am having trouble is sending JSON objects to server.
What should i use to accomplish that.Volley or Retrofit?

Comment: just send object as string  like jsonObject.toString()